# session_start gives notice that its already started.

Tags: php, session

I have a php file which starts a session, this is followed by some html. Later i include another file using `include "some_file.php"`. The `some_file.php` has php and mysql interaction which is used to populate a table. Now i am starting a session in some_file.php as well, as i need to access the session variables. However i thought that the by using include i won't have to start a session again. But on doing this i get an error saying undefined session variable in `some_file.php`, and by using it, i get a notice saying 
`Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in some_file.php/some_line`

Comment: Your included files shouldn't have session_start().  Remove this from the included files, just have it once in your file that includes the others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't make sure your session is always started, you have to check if its started:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
 session_start();
}
```

Comment: For some reason this works in my included file. I don't know how my session is being unset! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: only available from PHP >=5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You only have to start `session_start()` once.

Comment: But i gives my an error for the session variable saying `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in some_file`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have `session_start()` **once** after connecting to your database (if you have one) and before outputting anything at all to the browser. Make sure there is no white space in front of     `session_start()` to minimize accidental output.